# Proguard for static builder class

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I am trying to keep the parameters name in one of my builder static class.

here is my raw code.

```
public final class Settings {
...
    public static class Builder{

    setPropertyOne(String prop1){
    ...}

    setIntDef(@MyIntDef int myId){
    ...}

}
```

Here is after obfuscation

```
public final class Settings {
...
    public static class Builder{

    setPropertyOne(String s){
    ...}

    setIntDef(int i){
    ...}

}
```

The proguard file I used here is

```
-keep class my.path.Settings{
    *;
}

-keep public class my.path.Settings$*{
    *;
}

-keepattributes *Annotation*, MethodParameters
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the whole class from being obfuscated, you can use the following:

```
-keep class com.yourpath.Settings**
-keepclassmembers com.yourpath.Settings** {*;}
```

Or you can use `@Keep` annotation above your class name to prevent it from obfuscation.